# Add a large letter before each Glossary section with words starting with that letter

Tags: glossary

I'm hoping to have the following:

> A
>
> abscissa - another term for an x-coordinate
>
> B
>
> bisector - description
>
> ...

With the letters in larger text, but when I do `\newglossaryentry{A}{name=\LARGE{A}, description = {some description}`, I get a

> improper alphabetic constant

error, since only text can come after `name=`. Does anyone know a way around this?  I figured out how to make a style file to do this for the index, so if the simpler solution doesn't work I would love to know how to code that in the glossaries style.

Comment: Juat a guess, but try \protect\LARGE...

Comment: If the comment by John Kormylo didn't work, could you make a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please and edit it into your question? It doesn't need to be a big document but just something so we can trial solutions on etc, the `\documentclass` you are using could even influence the answer so we need more information please

Comment: I tried \protect and it didn't work, but good suggestion.  I also tried \ErrorFilter in the silence package for the "improper alphabetic constant" error code (since it compiles the way I want in the pdf) but that didn't work either.  I'm using the book document class.

Hopefully this MWE works:

Main File:

\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\makenoidxglossaries

\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossname}{firstuc}

\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdesc}{firstuc}
\input{glossary}

Glossary File:

\newglossaryentry{A}{name=A, description={\phantom{A}}}

Comment: It doesn't have any problem with the \phantom{}

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, I needed to put `\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist,sanitizesort]{glossaries-extra}` in the preamble.